# Cauchy's integral formula and essential singularities

Tags: cv.complex-variables, sequences-and-series, integral-transforms

Let $f$ be holomorphic at $z_0\in\mathbb C$. I would like to compute the integral
$$\oint_{\gamma_{z_0}} f(z)\, e^{\frac{1}{z-z_0}}dz,$$
where $\gamma_{z_0}$ is a small circle around $z_0$.
By expanding the exponential, I find that
$$\oint_{\gamma_{z_0}} f(z)\, e^{\frac{1}{z-z_0}}dz=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\oint_{\gamma_{z_0}} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz.$$
The integral can be evaluated using Cauchy's integral formula,
$$\oint_{\gamma_{z_0}} f(z)\, e^{\frac{1}{z-z_0}}dz=2\pi i\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!(n+1)!},$$
with $f^{(n)}$ the $n$-the derivative of $f$.

It seems that the result could be related more directly to $f$, having similarities with the Taylor series $f$. To be precise, if the $(n+1)!$ was removed, the result would be $2 \pi i f(z_0+1)$. I was wondering

a) if such Borel-like sums have been studied for Taylor series of holomorphic functions, and

b) if there is a more direct relation between the period integral and $f$ that would allow to compute the series.

Many thanks for sharing your ideas!
PS: I have already posted the question on [SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4375049/600723) and have received no feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote: "I was wondering [...] if there is a more direct relation between the period integral and $f$ that would allow to compute the series."

We can try the simple and specific case when $f(z)=e^{-z^2}$ and $z_0=1$.  Then, up an explicit constant factor, the series is
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n H_n(1)}{n! (n+1)!},$$
where $H_n$ is the $n$th Hermite polynomial.

Mathematica cannot do anything to compute this series. So, the answer to your question b) is very likely no.

---

Here is the image of the corresponding Mathematica notebook:

[image]

---

Even in the more specific case when $f(z)=e^{z^2/2}$ and $z_0=0$ (so that $f^{(n)}(z_0)=(n-1)!!\,(1+(-1)^n)/2$), Mathematica can only give the tautological expression:

[image]

---

However, Mathematica can do the case $f(z)=e^z$ :-) :

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't say that if Mathematica cannot process an expression that there is no way to simplify or find an underlying structure. For $f=\text{exp}$ for example, the series equals $2\pi i I_0(2\sqrt z)$, the modified Bessel function of the first kind. At the very least, this map should be nontrivial and interesting if restricted to generalised hypergeometric functions.

Comment: @S.Rachmaninov : Yes, Mathematica is fine with $f=\exp$. I have added more details. Do you have examples you can do but Mathematica really cannot?

Comment: `Residue[Exp[1/z], {z, 0}]`

Comment: @S.Rachmaninov : It is indeed strange that Mathematica cannot execute this command. However, we were talking about computing series rather than residues per se. The case in your latest comment is when $f(z)=1$ and $z_0=0$. In this case, the series has only one nonzero term, and Mathematica will have no problem computing this series. Note also that $f(z)=1$ is the particular, limit instance of $f(z)=e^{tz}$ for $t\ne0$, in which case Mathematica has no problem computing the value $I_1\left(2 \sqrt{t}\right)/\sqrt{t}$ of the series.

Comment: Previous comment continued: Anyhow, we saw that Mathematica cannot evaluate the series even in simplest explicitly given cases. Given the high degree of Mathematica's proficiency in such problems, it is indeed highly unlikely that the series can be evaluated in general.

Comment: I totally agree with you, the point was just to give an example of something that I can easily compute but Mathematica can't. While I do have a specific function $f$ in mind that I want to compute this contour integral of, I was intrigued by the simple relation of the Taylor series of the transformed function and the function itself, and was hoping there would be some general theory behind it that would allow me to find alternative descriptions or methods to compute such integrals in practise.